# ESLint Must use destructuring state assignment

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I am getting ESlint error for the following line `this.state.items.map(item => (`

The error is `Must use destructuring state assignment`

```
{
            this.state.items.map(item => (
              <div key={item}>
                {
                item.links.map(thing => (
                  <NavLink
                    key={thing.link.id}
                    exact
                    to={thing.link.url}
                  >
                    {thing.link.text}
                  </NavLink>
                ))
                }
              </div>
            ))
          }
```

I am using "eslint-config-airbnb"

Also, this is my componentDidMount function if this is related

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetch('./data/data_arr.js')
  .then(results => results.json())
  .then(results => this.setState({ items: results }));
}
```

Any help to try and understand this would be great. thank you

Comment: You don't need to ask a question about linter warnings each time you get one :) Just use your linter warning line. There will be some hints, URLs that directing you to the right place like @Nguyễn Thanh Tú did their provided answer. Or, at least Google it :)

Comment: Details of this lint rule GitHub - [Enforce consistent usage of destructuring assignment of props, state, and context](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/destructuring-assignment.md)

Comment: @devserkan Greetings from Google!

Answer (score 39):

That's called:

> Enforce consistent usage of destructuring assignment of props, state,
>   and context (react/destructuring-assignment)

More details are available here: [destructuring-assignment](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/destructuring-assignment.md)

In order to make that warning/error disappear, you could do like this:

```
      ...
      const { items }= this.state;
      ...
      {
        items.map(item => (
          <div key={item}>
            {
            item.links.map(thing => (
              <NavLink
                key={thing.link.id}
                exact
                to={thing.link.url}
              >
                {thing.link.text}
              </NavLink>
            ))
            }
          </div>
        ))
      }
```

Comment: My confusion is... why is this a rule? It seems like the documentation should make a case for itself, maybe recognize trade-offs.

Comment: I also wonder why it is so in most practices? Because in good coding practice, where I read from [the book Clean Code by Robert Cecil Martin](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3735293-clean-code) it is better to keep as near as possible the source of the variable (from where it comes) to avoid unnecessary scrolls up and down. Can anyone inform me please, if there is a serious issue about this?

Comment: It's simply to avoid redundant `this.props` / `this.state` in the code, and to improve readability. It is not very relevant with this exemple, but it is so much cleaner in real world.

Comment: yeah if I'm looking at a component for the first time, I kind of like to obviously see if things are bound from state or props right in the markup

Comment: Its almost a pointless rule, is the only reason to stop you setting state directly accidentally?