# Must use destructuring props assignment issue

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I was making an app in react-native and when I try to put on text one of the values of props, I get an error message like this: `Must use destructuring props assignment`

The code is this:

```
<Text style={styles.SubTextButton}>
      {props.date1} - {props.date2}
</Text>
```

and the props look like this:

```
(props: {
  text: string
  date1: string
  date2: string
})
```

The thing is, this actually don't ruin my app and all work well. But I would like to know if it is maybe a question of format in the writing of the code or even an error of the ESlinter.

Comment: It's not an "error", it's saying that the way your linter is currently configured it wants you to use prop destructuring instead of accessing through props.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ESLint Must use destructuring state assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52638426/eslint-must-use-destructuring-state-assignment)

Comment: Y'all were right! Also the old post answers my question! Thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get this warning because in your Eslint set the rule: `"react/destructuring-assignment": [<enabled>, 'always']`

Eslint wants you write in this way with using destructuring assignment:

```
const MyComponent = ({ date1, date2 }) => {
  return (
    <Text>
      {date1} - {date2}
    </Text>
  )
}
```

Comment: Yeah! This is a solution!

Comment: @RafaRoman I'm glad to hear you could find it useful. Do not forget to accept the answer =)